# How to remove "space" in input data?

Tags: php

I have problem to form input data, where if me input data with "space" a lot, no word and numbers if me call post data that, data cannot be called

How me prevent "space excessive" at the beginning of the word? and how if me use space in word me ?

I don't want to input data using excessive "space" at the beginning of data input because My link URL error unreadable because the post is empty.

me use (preg_match)

maybe someone here can help my problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. I guess you are using a translator so I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but take a look at [trim function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: oke, sorry my word bad. i will click your link, who knows I found what I was looking for.

Comment: If you are looking at leading or trailing spaces use trim() function
$name = trim($_POST['name']);

Comment: @Khadreal, Thank's

Comment: If you found a answer, Remember to add the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** If you are talking about leading or trailing spaces then use trim() function.

`$username =trim($username);`

**2)** But if you are talking about middle spaces then do with preg_replace():-

`$username = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $username);`

**3)** You can go with str_replace() also:-

`$username = str_replace(' ','',$username);`

Comment: I replaced `str_replce()` by `str_replace()`. Feel free to remove my comment.

Comment: @t.ahso. Please upvote this solution if it's really helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function in my private library:

```
function xtrim ( $str )
{
    return trim(preg_replace('/\\s+/',' ',$str));
}
```

First, all groups of blanks (white spaces) are replaced by exact one space. Then `trim()` removes spaces at both ends.